# Смена изображения в коде WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

В Xaml я задаю путь к изображению:

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="<тут путь>\Images\1.png"/>
```

Как мне в коде изменить путь к картинке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
image.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(@"<путь>\Images\1.png"));
```

Если картинка лежит в файловой системе, то `path` — путь к ней. Если картинка лежит в ресурсах (то есть, влинкована в сборку), то вам нужно использовать [Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/1.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

обращаясь через свойство .ImageSource в image